# Tracing DNS request

Tags: linux, debian, dns

I have static IP in my Debian Lenny system and ping by IP to Internet works fine. Unfortunately www.google.com is not resolved by name. I can't install any additional software to my Linux since it does not resolves names.

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
# Used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8). See the interfaces(5) manpage or
# /usr/share/doc/ifupdown/examples for more information.

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface uses static address
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.99
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        network 192.168.1.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

How to trace DNS request with standard tools in order to find problem?

Comment: what is in `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: Like @ctrl-alt-delor said, please edit your question and include the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`.  Also, is `ping 8.8.8.8` successful?

Comment: `/etc/resolv.conf` contained wrong IP. I was expecting `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8` is main place for DNS server

Comment: @vico have you answered your own question? If so then put it in the answer section.

Comment: I would like to clarify why `resolv.conf` is stronge then `dns-nameservers`

Comment: Then please post the (original) content of the `resolv.conf` file. No one can tell you why it was wrong otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this could be a DNS resolution issue on your Debian device.

Try this:

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf # create the file and add the statement as first line
echo "nameserver 8.8.4.4" >> /etc/resolv.conf # append to existing file at the end
```

This should fix your issue.